# Grep string inside double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Trying to grep a string inside double quotes at the moment I use this

```
grep user file | grep -e "[\'\"]"
```

This will get to the section of the file I need and highlight the double quotes but it will not give the sting in the double quotes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ cat aaaa
foo"bar"base
$ grep -oP '"\K[^"\047]+(?=["\047])' aaaa
bar
```

I use *look around* advanced *regex* techniques.

If you want the quotes too :

```
$ grep -Eo '["\047].*["\047]'
"bar"
```

Note :

```
\047
```

is the octal ascii representation of the single quote

Comment: Thanks it nearly works - the output gets the string as well as ; outside the double quote

Comment: Nope just the sting but using the above grep gives me ; as well... try  this for example user="bobhope";

Comment: @GillesQuenot How to use inside package.json I cannot use right now in todo script.

"img-altchk": "gulp img-altchk",
    "todo": "grep -lir /<img(\s*(?!alt)([\w\-])+=([\"\'])[^\"\']+\3)*\s*\/?>/"
  },

Comment: Don't use regex to parse JSON but a JSON library

Answer (score 9):

```
$ cat aaaa
foo"bar"base

$ grep -o '"[^"]\+"'
"bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
grep "Test" /tmp/junk | tr '"' ' '
```

This will remove quotes from the output of grep

Or you could try the following:

```
grep "Test" /tmp/junk | cut -d '"' -f 2
```

This will use the quotes as a delimiter. Just specify the field you want to select. This lets you cherry-pick the information you want.

Comment: Ironically, both of these yield a blank line when piped onto `grep -o '"[^"]\+"'`, but `grep -Eo '".*"' | tr -d '"'` worked.

Comment: `cut` is not a good choice here because the information is not separated into fields. The number of quotes in a line could be 1, could be 5, could be none.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.
This will print the data including the double quotes also.

```
 grep -o '"[^"]\+"' file.txt
```

If we want to print without double quotes, then we need to pipe the grep output to a sed command.

```
grep -o '"[^"]\+"' file.txt | sed 's/"//g'
```